# Does an if statement return immediately when one of the conditions is false

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm curious about optimization opportunities by changing the order of conditions in an `if` statement.

Given the example below, if `x` is false, will the `if` statement try to execute the other two conditions. If it won't, should I include them in an `if` branch. Also at what order do they execute. Is it left to right or is it right to left?

```
if (x && y && z)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check is done from left to right - if X is false, the if statement will return right away.

Think about code with null checking, for example. You would write

```
if(list != null && list.count > 10) {
// do something
}
```

but not

```
if(list.count > 10 && list != null) {
// the null check here does not help you
}
```

Comment: Do you know any documentation about this or any link from microsoft .net? or source code

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators

Answer (score 2):

In c#,

`if(X&y&z){}`
using **logical operator** `&` always evaluates all statements.
On the contrary, if you use **conditional logical operators** `&&` for conditional logical AND and `||` for conditional logical OR, statements are evaluated left to right and right hand statements are evaluated only if necessary.

```
if (x & y) {}
```

always evaluates both x and y, while

```
if (x && y) {}
```

Only evaluates y if x is false.
For reference check:

[Microsoft .NET documentation on Boolean logical operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Comment: Thanks i was tired i typed it all wrong but you understood what i meant

Comment: What you typed was not wrong. Just different. Both `&` and `&&` can be used, they just have different meanings.

Comment: Be careful with the logical operators (like `&` and `|`). The conditional operators (like `&&` and `||`) only work with boolean operands. However, the logical operators work with both boolean and integral types. If you use them with booleans, you get the non-sohort-circuiting logical behavior described above. However, if you use them with integers, you get a bitwise operation (for example, 14 (1110 in binary) anded with 7 (0111) would result in 6 (0110): (14 & 7) == 6.

Comment: @Flydog57 indeed, very true. The original question was about logical operators, then the OP edited it to conditional logical ops after my answer.

Comment: Interestingly, idiomatic C# and idiomatic VB do things differently. Most of the time, C# programmers work with the short-circuiting `&&` and `||`. However,  in VB, programmers usually use the non-short-circuiting `AND` and `OR`. You rarely see the short-circuiting version (`AndAlso` and `OrElse`). Both uses are based on the idioms of their predecessor languages (C and pre-.NET VB).